# How display an image in a div in html using response from fetch data from api?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm trying to display an image in a div in html. I used fetch to get the json data from the api : https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/435828. The response gives json date with the image url named "primaryImage". I'm able to display it in text but not as an image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Image</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<img id="test">

<script>


    let getimage = document.getElementbyId('test');
    getimage.src= "data"

    fetch('https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/435828')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => texting.innerText = data.primaryImage);

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your sample page,

replace;

```js
.then((data) => texting.innerText = data.primaryImage);
```

line with;

```js
.then(data => getimage.src = data.primaryImage);
```

Comment: I'm still unable to view the image. When i inspect the console there's an error saying Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function.

Comment: @Tan, that is indeed not a function, the correct spelling is: `document.getElementById` with a B instead of b

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that. Now its showing an image placeholder and console says 1) Failed to load resource and 2) Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: texting is not defined at append?

Answer (score 0):

The process is fairly simple and can be described as follows:

- cache your `image` in a variable so that you can access it later.
- make a request to your `API`.
- then parse the API response as `JSON`.
- then update the `image` source, or specifically the `src` attribute, as the `API` response's `primaryImage` field.

Here's a live demo to illustrate:

```js
// cache the image element so we can access it later
const img = document.getElementById('test');

// make a request to your API
fetch('https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/435828')
// parse the API response as "JSON"
.then(r => r.json())
// update the image's "src" (source)
.then(r => img.src = r.primaryImage);
```

```html
<img id="test">
```

You might as well think of adding a loading text or spinner while the image loads but am not going into that as it'll make my answer out of scope.

> Just keep in mind that's not always the case as APIs can be different and the way they return their response can change. Anyway, most case will be the same though.

> I recommend you take a look at the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and how it works.